# What to use instead of BREAK ( PYTHON )

Tags: python

In this example I was wondering what I could use instead of BREAK

```
while (True):
    try:
        guess = ***********
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(***)
```

Comment: Why do you need to use something else?

Comment: A `return` can also end a loop, but only from inside a function.

Comment: Why do you need a `break` in the very first iteration of the loop and also without any condition? this is equivalent to not having the `while` loop and `break` at all :)

Comment: @Lawliet The part replaced by stars could be something like `int(input())` which would raise a `ValueError` if the input isn't a valid `int`, so the loop ensures that the user will be asked again until he gives a valid input.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize `guess` to an invalid value and test for that.

```
guess = None
while guess is None:
    try:
        guess = int(input('Please enter your guess for the roll: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Only enter a number please')
```

When there's no error, `guess` will be set to an integer, which is not `None`, so the loop will end.

But I prefer your original code, it's clearer.

Comment: Actually, I prefer this, since the intent of the loop is clearer, and you can always add other non-exception checks with `if guess < 1 or guess > 6:`, `print("It's only a six-sided dice")`, `guess = None`.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a more information.

```
loop = True
while (loop):
    try:
        guess = int(input('Please enter your guess for the roll: '))
        loop =False
        #break
    except ValueError:
        print('Only enter a number please')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using a some lesser known but useful python control flows include using a `for/else` and `try/except/else`, it still requires a `break` but i think it's still a neat alternative

```
MAX_GUESS = 3
for _ in range(MAX_GUESS):
    try:
        guess = int(input('Input guess: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Try again!")
    else:
        print("Success!")
        break
else:
    guess = None
    print("Max guesses attempted")
```

The `else` block tied to the `for/else` loop is only entered if a `break` was NOT encountered during the loop, similarly the `else` of the `try/except/else` is only entered if an exception was NOT raised during the `try`